# when input's type is password,it's always contain data "1"

Tags: html, firefox, passwords

My code is

```
<html>
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <input type="password" id="txtNewpasswd"  />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in FireFox 20.0.1, It's always like this...why ???  Who can help me???

[image: the reuslt]

Comment: you might have cached data in your FF browser you can check it by clearing the cache in for any saved form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this is a saved password.

Firefox will ask if you want to save the content of `password` fields and will then auto-complete this data on load.

Try adding the `autocomplete` attribute:

```
<input type="password" id="txtNewpasswd" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: @santanukumar I don't understand the question. If you want to disable autocomplete when you need to add the property to disable autocomplete. If you don't want to disable autocomplete then you do not need to add this property.

Comment: but do @jasonLam want to disable the autocomplete or do he want to know why is like this :)

Comment: 3Q.It works ,but it's the only way?Or in ohter words, this problem just in FireFox ?

Comment: @jasonLam this isn't a problem! This is just that you clicked on the "save password for this site" button and it did. If you want it never to do that then this will stop that behaviour. Otherwise don't click on the save password button and it won't.

Comment: @santanu kumar  I want to disable the autocomplete  and I want to know why is like this    ah. you got it

Comment: thats what i asked if you want to disable it then you can use autocomplete off but you can clear the previous stored values from the browser too :) the reason is you have saved a value previously in your FF browser which is showing by default for your password field..

Comment: I cleared all the cooikes,sessions and so on ...even if I created a new page and open it in FF,it's always like this.By the way,my FF's version is 20.0.1

Comment: @santanukumar is plain wrong. This is **not** a cached value it is a **saved password** as I keep saying. Read [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords).

Comment: OK, I knew it .. because my website has a login page,it's password is "1" ,so in this page, FF still rememered it and fill in the type is password's input    Is that right? :) 3Q,everybody

Comment: @BoristheSpider the Spider i have told saved form data or stored values not website cache :)

Comment: Yes, both of you are right .I didn't think it at first , so ...but there is another thing that very funny: in the same page, there are three password inputs , but only one of them fill the website's password.